# SwiftUI retuning List or NavigationView in body: difference of return List and List in body

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I have question about returning `NavigationView` and `List` inside of SwiftUI `body`

There are code snippets like this:

```swift
    var body: some View {
      let trailingItem = HStack {
        Button(action: { print("Button 1") }) {
          Image(systemName: "bell")
        }
        Button(action: { print("Button 2") }) {
          Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
        }
      }
      
      return NavigationView {
        Image("SwiftUI")
          .navigationBarItems(trailing: trailingItem)
          .navigationBarTitle("Title")
      }
    }
```

and this

```swift
    var body: some View {
      let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

      return List(numbers, id: \.self) {
        Text("\(String(describing: $0))")
      }
    }
```

In these two code snippets, I can find `return` keyword for `NavigationView` and `List`
To figure out what does that grammar do, I tried deleting `return` keyword but nothing happened

I want to know:
**What does that `return` keyword do?**

**What is difference between using `return` for `NavigationView` and `List`**

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the features in SwiftUI's syntax are made possible by something called a [View Builder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) which is a type of [Result Builder](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deep-dive-into-swift-function-builders/)

When using a View Builder, functions and computed properties have an implicit return (ie the last statement is returned even without the `return` keyword). There are also other specific rules about what kinds of implicit code can be included in a View Builder, but `let` declarations like your examples contain are fine. See https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/18/the-power-of-viewbuilder-in-swiftui/ and https://swiftontap.com/viewbuilder for more information.

SwiftUI `View`s are an interesting special case because the `var body` property of the `View` is interpreted to be a `ViewBuilder` even though we don't have to explicitly annotate it with `@ViewBuilder`. However, if you were to try the same thing in a regular function, you would need to use that `@ViewBuilder` to get a similar result if the function had more than one statement (one-line functions in Swift have implicit returns as well).

```
@ViewBuilder func myView() -> some View {
    Text("test")
    Text("Another item")
}
```

So, in your code examples (since you were in `var body`), there is no difference between using `return` and omitting it.